# Flex UI Inconsistencies

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface

I am having some issue with consistency across different machines with my flex application.

There are three things that I have noticed with my application. On my development machine (Windows XP) I **can not** reproduce these issues.

I have noticed them on a Windows Vista machine as well as a Windows 7 machine.

The three things that I have found are:

1. Label's will be truncated with '...'
2. Tabs in a tab navigator will be truncated with a '...'
3. Some Images will be rendered with an inconsistent width and height

My labels are defined pretty simply

```
<mx:Label x="261" y="15" text="Date Prepared" fontWeight="bold" width="113"/>
```

Tabs are custom components but defined in a pretty standard format:

```
    <mx:TabNavigator borderStyle="solid" 
        x="10" y="10" width="665" height="450" id="tabs" creationPolicy="all">
    <local:FormPanel id="formPanel" name="formPanel" 
           label="Incident Details  " 
           width="665" height="450"/>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
```

You may notice extra white space following the label in the custom FormPanel, I have found that this might help solve a subset of the truncation issues (not 100% sure).

As for my images, again, I am not doing anything to amazing:

```
<mx:Image id="vehicle_image" 
    source="@Embed(source='../../../../../images/icons/basic/vehicles.swf')"
    height="45" width="45" toolTip="Vehicles" 
    toolTipShow="handleToolTipShow(event)"
    click="showBar(event, vehicle_bar)" enabled="true" x="47" y="0"/>
```

The image is contained in a canvas and I will have about 10 of these images all sized 45x45. On certain machines I will see 3 of the 10 images rendered smaller what would appear about 30x30 relative to the other 45x45 sized images.

The problem I am having is that I can not reproduce these issues on my development machine, and do not have any clue on how to fix these issues. I would expect that the things I am seeing are bugs in the FlexSDK, but even if they are bugs I do need a temporary work around.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the browsers using the same version of the Flash plugin?

Comment: They should all be using the same version of Adobe AIR. I forgot to mention that the application is an AIR app.

Comment: What is your truncation problem?  That items are truncating or that they are not?  I'm pretty sure the '...' comes from a resourceManager which is part of the player [I assume in some config file somewhere].  You dev machine may have become corrupted somehow.  A full runnable sample would be beneficial here.

Comment: In certain environments they are truncating, which I would want the correct behavior to be never truncating, just scaling the labels so that they always display correctly.

The dev machine is not the one that shows this behavior. It is on other client machines.

Comment: Move to percentage width / heights to resize your app to different screen sizes.  However, most Flex containers have a "measuredMinWidth" and "measuredMinHeight" which most containers will honor; thus forcing either scrollbars or truncation as you see.  I believe that is what you're asking for as opposed to scaleX / scaleY.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it won't let me add a comment, but..
This sounds a lot like some of the changes (CSS fixes) put in from Flex 2 to 3 (maybe 3 to 4 as well?)  (Button components can do this too if the width is a fixed size.)

Are you **absolutely sure** that your development machine is running the same version of the app as the others?  If you're using Flex/Flash Builder's "run" functionality to run on the dev machine, but building and deploying with Flex Ant tasks or some kind of separate build for the others, it's possible to have this happen by using different SDKs even though the code hasn't been changed at all.

Comment: Yes. I create a .air file using Flex Builder 3 and then email that out to the clients.

I am currently in the process of upgrading from Flex3 to Flex4, this is a bit painful, but once done hopefully it will resolve some of these issues.

Comment: Which version of AIR do they all have installed? (Assuming they're all the same of course.) Is it one of the 2.0 betas? Perhaps an AIR bug? It's definitely unusual, a small example uploaded to something like megaupload to duplicate the issue would be interesting.

Comment: Came back to suggest trying an embedded font, but then you still have image size problems. Bizarre! http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_05.html

Comment: Yeah... I am still having this issue. I think it might be useful to create a minimal example and see if it happens.

Comment: I am using .swf files for the images and it appears to consistently be the same images that have the funny behavior, maybe it is some kind of bug with those particular images. Maybe a modification and re-encoding of them might solve the problem.